# Distance matrix of matrices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data-set which contains measurements of 10 interfaces (denoted as A, B,.., J). Each Interface has 3 sensors - so for interface A, we'll denote these sensors as A1, A2, A3.

My goal is to measure the differences between the measurements of different interfaces.  I thought it's best to use [Frobenius Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm), that is - for 2 matrices A, B the norm is defined as:

[image]

It means that eventually I want a 10x10 symmetric matrix with the matrices distances (the diagonal is zeroed, of course).

My data set is a CSV file with ~25K rows and 30 columns (10 interfaces * 3 sensors). What is the best way to perform this calculation using python (with `numpy` and `pandas`)? I know how to do it for columns (using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances` for example), but I didn't find an elegant way to enhance it for matrices.

**EDIT**:

A small example of how my data-set looks like (Instead of the row numbers there are time-stamps, not that it matters too much...):

```
     A1    A2    A3    ...    J1   J2   J3
1   3.2   12.9  -7.8  ...    5.5  11.2  -6.9
2   3.4   12.7  -8.0  ...    5.6  11.3  -7.9
3   3.2   12.9  -7.8  ...    5.6  11.4  -7.6
```

Comment: I don't think it's productive to ask "the best way". What is your constraints for "good enough solution"? Memory complexity, time complexity?

Comment: As long as it doesn't take eternity to calculate - it's good for me (meaning, no actual constraints...)

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of your problem? Not 25K of rows and maybe just 6-9 columns?

Comment: @AlexYu I added an example of 3 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Frobenius norm for matrices is just the same as the traditional 2-norm on the corresponding flattened vectors - so it seems like you can just flatten each of the `N*3` matrices into a `3N*1` vector, resulting in a `3N*10` array overall, where `N` is your number of rows? At that point you can call pairwise distance functions like the ones you mentioned that work with columns.

Example of how to do this transformation in one line when `N=200`:

```
In [2]: x = np.empty((200,30))

In [3]: y = x.T.reshape(10,-1).T

In [4]: y.shape
Out[4]: (600, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html))

Example:

```
df
>>     A1    A2   A3   J1    J2   J3  B1  B2  B3
1  3.2  12.9 -7.8  5.5  11.2 -6.9   3   1   2
2  3.4  12.7 -8.0  5.6  11.3 -7.9   3   1   2
3  3.2  12.9 -7.8  5.6  11.4 -7.6   3   1   2

from scipy.spatial import distance
groups = [['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], ['J1', 'J2', 'J3']]

# based on your formula, simply flatten the data to take element-wise distance
dist = distances(distance.pdist([df[group].values.flatten() for group in groups]))
dist
>> array([26.69138438,  4.88364618, 24.6462979 ])

# if you want matrix form
distance.squareform(dist)
>>array([[ 0.        , 26.69138438,  4.88364618],
   [26.69138438,  0.        , 24.6462979 ],
   [ 4.88364618, 24.6462979 ,  0.        ]])
```